# Parsing date, time and zone to UTC datetime object

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz

As part of a logging system, I would like to parse a string timestamp coming from a Cisco device, which has the following format:

```
# show clock
16:26:19.990 GMT+1 Wed Sep 11 2013
```

The parsing result should be a UTC `datetime` instance which will be stored in a SQLite database, thus the need for a timezone conversion.

Using just `datetime.strptime` is not enough, because the `%Z` directive only recognises local timezones (i.e. those related to the current `$LANG` or `$LC_*` environment).  Therefore, I need to make use of the [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) package.

Because the format is always the same, I can do something like the following:

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

s = '16:26:19.990 CEST Wed Sep 11 2013'
tm, tz, dt = s.split(" ", 2)
naive = datetime.strptime("%s %s" % (tm, dt), "%H:%M:%S.%f %a %b %d %Y")
aware = naive.replace(timezone=pytz.timezone(tz))
universal = aware.astimezone(pytz.UTC)
```

This, however, does not work without some modifications.  The value of `tz` must be corrected to a name that is recognized by pytz.  In the example, `pytz.timezone('CEST')` raises an `UnknownTimezoneError` because the real timezone is `CET`.  The problem is that the daylight savings correction is not applied then:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> from pytz import UTC, timezone
>>> a = datetime.strptime('16:18:57.925 Wed Sep 11 2013', '%H:%M:%S.%f %a %b %d %Y')
>>> b = a.replace(tzinfo=timezone('CET'))
>>> a
datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 11, 16, 18, 57, 925000)
>>> b
datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 11, 16, 18, 57, 925000, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'CET' CET+1:00:00 STD>)
>>> b.astimezone(UTC)
datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 11, 15, 18, 57, 925000, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Using `normalize` does not seem to help:

```
>>> timezone('CET').normalize(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/etanol/virtualenvs/plexus/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytz/tzinfo.py", line 235, in normalize
    raise ValueError('Naive time - no tzinfo set')
ValueError: Naive time - no tzinfo set
>>> timezone('CET').normalize(b)
datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 11, 17, 18, 57, 925000, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'CET' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)
```

I don't really know what am I missing, but the wanted result is:

```
datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 11, 14, 18, 57, 925000, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post some additional examples of the input "time zone" string?  Is it always `"GMT"` +/- some number? Or are there other possibilities?

Comment: The first code snippet contains `CEST`

Comment: You should be very careful, time zone abbreviations can be ambiguous, and are not always agreed upon.  pytz is using the abbreviations from the IANA/Olson time zone db, but it's quite possible your cisco device has it's own hard-coded list.  It's also quite possible the cisco device doesn't take DST into account properly or stay updated with changes.  Without more detail, it's hard to say.

Comment: I had in mind a kind of mapping to resolve this: code => (code, is_dst).  Sure, this is not perfect but is the closest I can get with this little amount of code.  And sure, a Cisco device can have DST configuration completely broken, but it is out of the scope.

Comment: What kind of cisco device exactly is this?  A model number would help.

Comment: Not really.  I have the issue solved now.  But thanks for your interest ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `timezone.localize`:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> from pytz import UTC, timezone
>>>
>>> CET = timezone('CET')
>>>
>>> a = datetime.strptime('16:18:57.925 Wed Sep 11 2013', '%H:%M:%S.%f %a %b %d %Y')
>>> print CET.localize(a).astimezone(UTC)
2013-09-11 14:18:57.925000+00:00
```